# How come the definition of analytic continuation doesn't require the smaller and the bigger open subsets to be connected?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, laurent-series, taylor-expansion

The reason that is making me think that these subsets should be connected / simpled connected is because I think that the Taylor disks of convergence of f and F, which is the continuation of f to the bigger subset of the complex plane, should be connected / simply connected.

But Wiki does not even mention connectedness in defining analytic continuation.

Thanks,

Comment: You are right about the bigger set, but the smaller set need not be connected. The theorem states that if $f(z_n)=0$ for a sequence $\{z_n\}$ with a limit point (for example, if $f(z)=0$ identically in an open set) inside some connected region $\Omega$, then $f$ is identically zero in $\Omega$.